How to resolve the error, Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String
I am implementing the process of borrowing a book using angular and springboot but I am getting the error Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String.
Here is my Angular code:
borrowBook(book: BookResponse) {
    this.message = "";
    this.bookService.borrowBook({
      'book-id': book.id as number
    }).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.level = 'success';
        this.message = "Book successfully added to your list";
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.level = 'error';
        this.message = err.error.error;
      }
    });
  }

In Spring boot,
this is my controller method :
@PostMapping("borrow/{book-id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> borrowBook(
            @PathVariable("book-id") Integer bookId,
            Authentication connectedUser
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.borrowBook(bookId, connectedUser));
    }

The logic is as below:
public Integer borrowBook(Integer bookId, Authentication connectedUser) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("No book found with ID:: " + bookId));
        if (book.isArchived() || !book.isShareable()) {
            throw new OperationNotPermittedException("The requested book cannot be borrowed since it is archived or not shareable");
        }
        User user = ((User) connectedUser.getPrincipal());
        if (Objects.equals(book.getOwner().getUser_id(), user.getUser_id())) {
            throw new OperationNotPermittedException("You cannot borrow your own book");
        }

        System.out.println("this works");
        final boolean isAlreadyBorrowedByUser = transactionHistoryRepository.isAlreadyBorrowedByUser(bookId, user.getUser_id());
        if (isAlreadyBorrowedByUser) {
            throw new OperationNotPermittedException("You already borrowed this book and it is still not returned or the return is not approved by the owner");
        }
        final boolean isAlreadyBorrowedByOtherUser = transactionHistoryRepository.isAlreadyBorrowed(bookId);
        if (isAlreadyBorrowedByOtherUser) {
            throw new OperationNotPermittedException("The requested book is already borrowed");
        }

        BookTransactionHistory bookTransactionHistory = BookTransactionHistory.builder()
                .user(user)
                .book(book)
                .isReturned(false)
                .isReturnApproved(false)
                .build();
        return transactionHistoryRepository.save(bookTransactionHistory).getId();  // line 186

    }

Here is my repository :
@Query("""
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(bookTransactionHistory) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END
            FROM BookTransactionHistory bookTransactionHistory
            WHERE bookTransactionHistory.user.user_id = :userId
            AND bookTransactionHistory.book.id = :bookId
            AND bookTransactionHistory.isReturnApproved = false
            """)
    boolean isAlreadyBorrowedByUser(@Param("bookId") Integer bookId, @Param("userId") Integer userId);

    @Query("""
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(bookTransactionHistory) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END
            FROM BookTransactionHistory bookTransactionHistory
            WHERE bookTransactionHistory.book.id = :bookId
            AND bookTransactionHistory.isReturnApproved = false
            """)
    boolean isAlreadyBorrowed(@Param("bookId") Integer bookId);

And the book entity is as follows:
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class BookTransactionHistory extends BaseEntity {

    // user relationship
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // book relationship
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;


    private boolean isReturned;
    private boolean isReturnApproved;
}

Here is the Stacktrace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String
at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3889)
at com.gichungasoftwares.book_network.history.BookTransactionHistory_Accessor_f4o9au.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.setProperty(InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SimplePersistentPropertyPathAccessor.setProperty(SimplePersistentPropertyPathAccessor.java:108)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SimplePersistentPropertyPathAccessor.setProperty(SimplePersistentPropertyPathAccessor.java:127)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory$MappingMetadataAuditableBeanWrapper.lambda$setProperty$0(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:232)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory$MappingMetadataAuditableBeanWrapper.setProperty(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:232)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory$MappingMetadataAuditableBeanWrapper.setCreatedBy(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandlerSupport.touchAuditor(AuditingHandlerSupport.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandlerSupport.lambda$touch$0(AuditingHandlerSupport.java:136)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandlerSupport.touch(AuditingHandlerSupport.java:134)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandlerSupport.markCreated(AuditingHandlerSupport.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markCreated(AuditingHandler.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate(AuditingEntityListener.java:92)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:55)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:72)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:199)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:757)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:741)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy156.persist(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:319)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy156.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:625)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:173)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:148)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy173.save(Unknown Source)
at com.gichungasoftwares.book_network.book.BookService.borrowBook(BookService.java:186)
at com.gichungasoftwares.book_network.book.BookController.borrowBook(BookController.java:99)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at com.gichungasoftwares.book_network.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

Here is the BaseEntity which defines the id fields
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

Base Entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;


    // Jpa Auditing Information
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    // from Application Auditor aware
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}

The above code is expected to report errors when a user borrows a book they own, they have already borrowed or have been borrowed by other users, otherwise return the id of the borrowed book. However, I am experiencing the above error, and I am thinking it has to do with the @Query in the repository. I have tried changing the borrowBook() return type to string but then i would have to return another field other than the id.

Help us help you - indicate which line of code throws this error, or better yet, add a a stacktrace.

@Sören and the code that probably helps fix the exception (the Book class) is missing.  My guess is that Book has an id field, which is a String.

@NickHolt it would fail on findById then, but it fails on persist.

@talexmovedtoCodidact maybe something to do with the column types on the underlying table that's storing BookTransactionHistory; same applies, the REST code is irrelevant, the problem is with JPA and the mapping.  I think the native query finders will work regardless leaving the save to fail.

@NickHolt The id  field is of type Integer

@Steve what does the table that's storing BookTransactionHistory look like?

@NickHolt  here is the table design -->  https://i.sstatic.net/gwsQqhNI.png

@Steve the Book 'find' methods appear to be functioning (as @talexmovedtoCodidact points out); I believe the native queries will work, leaving the mapping.  I'd suggest using H2 to write an integration test around the saving of BookTransactionHistory.

Just to be sure: Line 186 in BookService.java is the one that reads return transactionHistoryRepository.save(bookTransactionHistory).getId();, correct?

@Sören yes it is

@Sören yes, but the stack trace shows the error is happening in the depths of JPA, somewhere under the transactionHistoryRepository.save.

@Steve I can see AuditingEntityListener in the stack trace; what have you got configured regarding JPA Auditing?

@NickHolt I am including auditing information(creation date, last modified date, created by and last modified by ) whenever a book is updated. The createdBy and lastModifiedBy are of type String. I have included the BaseEntity where I have configured the Jpa Auditing

@Steve what is com.gichungasoftwares.book_network.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter doing, specifically, what type of 'principle' is it creating?

@NickHolt thank you, you have guided me to the right direction I had a problem with the way I had configured my Jpa Auditing... the user_id is of type Integer but I had configured the created_by as String in the BaseEntity

@steve no problem, got there in the end...

@NickHolt answer have guided me to the right direction. I had a problem with the way I had configured my Jpa Auditing... the user_id is of type Integer but I had configured the JpaAuditing info created_by as String in the BaseEntity class.
It should however be notable that the created_by data-type should match the userId data type in your User class.

So createdBy should be an Integer?

@rjdkolb It will depend on how you configure your user's id type

Can you edit your answer and put this in? It can help others.

@rjdkolb ok, sure
